# Watch os 2.0 Beta: Not Receiving notifications

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, notifications, apple-watch

I know it's not possible to ...:

- ... schedule notifications straight from the Watch, instead the watch has to deliver information to the iOS app, which will schedule it;
- ... decide where to show the notification. iOS Decides it for you instead;

With this in mind, I'm using the `WCSession::sendMessage` function to send a dictionary with all the info my iOS app needs to schedule a nofitication. When doing this with the simulator it works nicely, but when doing it on a real device it doesn't seem to work and I never receive a notification anywhere.

Any idea why my real devices (iOS9 iPhone 5c + Watch os 2.0 Beta 5) don't seem to want to schedule/trigger notifications?

As far as I understood it, it should show the notification on the watch if the iphone is locked, but on my simulator it seems to always do it on the iPhone, even though it is locked.

**Edit:**

After a suggestion, I checked out the device backlog via XCode and this is what I see appearing in that backlog when the watch tries to connect to the iPhone:

`Aug 21 11:25:16 glendcs-iPhone apsd[100] <Notice>: (Note ) WatchKit: SPDeviceConnection, createXPCConnection, invalidationHandler`

`Aug 21 11:25:16 glendcs-iPhone apsd[100] <Notice>: (Error) WatchKit: -[SPDeviceConnection activeComplicationsWithCompletion:] - error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service named com.apple.companionappd was invalidated from this process." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service named com.apple.companionappd was invalidated from this process.}`

`Aug 21 11:25:16 glendcs-iPhone companionappd[113] <Notice>: (Error) WatchKit: <SPCompanionAppServer.m -[SPCompanionAppServer listener:shouldAcceptNewConnection:]:763> process 100 is not entitled, so rejecting connection`

Comment: Are you seeing your iOS app get launched in response to the message being sent on the watch?

Comment: No, but according to [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WatchConnectivity/Reference/WCSession_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/WCSession/sendMessage:replyHandler:errorHandler:) it happens in the background if it has to wake it up, so I don't think I'm supposed to see it launching?

Comment: Yea, I didn't mean "launch as if user launched it"; I meant background launched. You can check if that is happening by adding logs and monitoring the device's console log in Xcode or by attaching to the process before it should launch in the background (Xcode will then be waiting to attach as soon as a process by the right name launches)

Comment: I tried that, and It seems to block the connection before it gets the chance to wake it up. I made an edit to my question @ccjensen. Hope that gives you a better idea of what's going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it myself. Apperently the problem was the beta versions of iOS9 and Watch OS 2 not matching up anymore. I upgraded my iOS a while ago to Beta 5, but forgot to do WatchOS, as I'm not used to this process. After syncing beta versions up today, connection between iOS and WatchOS was smooth :)

And for the first time I could also properly debug from XCode on the watch!